# error in launching emulator ver 2 -android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

please give me a step by step instruction to launch the emulator

am using vista 32bit,1gbRAM...emulator 1.5 launched and worked sucessfully...but why 2.0??

```
    [2012-01-06 13:36:29 - ISR] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android_2.1'
    [2012-01-06 13:36:34 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455
    [2012-01-06 13:36:34 - Emulator] 
    [2012-01-06 13:36:34 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
    [2012-01-06 13:36:34 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a high config machine 1 gb RAM looks too less.
Refer to the link below on the steps

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you've configured your emulator to use a lot of memory. Try to reduce it to 512MB.